# Sonar Runner : Windows 7 : Throwing error against jdbc on start

Tags: java, windows, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I'm going slowly mad.

I'm on windows 7 64 bit, using the latest SonarQube and runner 2.3.

I have SonarQube running against port 9000.

When I try to run sonar-runner.bat I get:

```
C:\myRoot\SonarQube\SonarQubeRunner\sonar-runner-dist-2.3\sonar-runner-2.3
SonarQube Runner 2.3
Java 1.7.0_45 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
Windows 7 6.1 amd64
INFO: Runner configuration file: C:\myRoot\SonarQube\SonarQubeRunner\sonar-runner-dist-2.3\sonar-runner-2.3\conf\sonar-runner.properties
INFO: Project configuration file: NONE
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "windows-1252" (analysis is platform dependent)
INFO: Work directory: C:\myRoot\SonarQube\sonar_examples\sonar-examples-master\projects\languages\php\php-sonar-runner\src\.sonar
INFO: SonarQube Server 4.0
14:18:52.103 INFO  - Load batch settings
14:18:52.196 INFO  - User cache: C:\Users\myName\.sonar\cache
14:18:52.212 INFO  - Install plugins
14:18:52.602 INFO  - Install JDBC driver
14:18:52.602 INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 1.700s
Final Memory: 4M/74M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
ERROR: Caused by: Fail to connect to database
ERROR: Caused by: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
ERROR: Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
ERROR:
ERROR: To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run SonarQube Runner with the -e switch.
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Runner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

When I collect the debug info I get:

```
        yadda, yadda ...
        ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1420)
        ... 37 more
```

I have a file called mysql-connector-java-5.1.26.jar at:

```
C:\myRoot\SonarQube\sonarqube-4.0\sonarqube-4.0\extensions\jdbc-driver\mysql
```

I can't think why it's not being found.

My .properities file is fairly simple.

ANY advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: In order for your JAR to be found, it must be in the classpath.  It looks like you are using some sort of .BAT file to execute this program.  I would start there and see if it has some sort of CLASSPATH variable defined.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message on my Jenkins setup using Linux Mint Debian Edition. I used SonarQube Runner 2.3 and SonarQube Server 4.1.1

```
ERROR: Unable to execute SonarERROR: Caused by: Fail to connect to database
ERROR: Caused by: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
ERROR: Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

[Here](http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/com-mysql-jdbc-Driver-is-not-found-td5012081.html) I read to restart the SonarQube server, which solved the issue for me.

I know it's trivial but that's all there was to it in my case and it's easy to overlook the little things.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying with your local Mysql data base then use these codes in your sonar.properties file of sonarcube.

```
# Permissions to create tables, indices and triggers must be granted to JDBC user.
# The schema must be created first.
sonar.jdbc.username=root
sonar.jdbc.password=root

#----- MySQL 5.x
# Comment the embedded database and uncomment the following line to use MySQL
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonardb?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true
sonar.jdbc.driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
sonar.jdbc.validationQuery: select 1
```

the last two line code is not specified in any of the sonar tutorials for Mysql.

And finally make sure you have created SONAR_RUNNER_HOME with proper value and the path variable entry up to the bin directory.